# Switching Screens with LibGDX is Slow on Android Device

Tags: java, android, performance, libgdx, screen

The screen is loading perfectly fine in Desktop mode, but the screen freezes for about a second or two before loading the next one on my HTC One M8.

This is happening to all my screens, so I'll just show two. I tried loading all the assets for the next screen in the previous screen, and then checking to see if they are loaded using `assets.update()` before loading the next screen, but the freeze still occurs.

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor {
    private Application game;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private Viewport viewport;

    private GameIcon gameIcon;
    private ParticleEffect effect;

    private MenuBackground mb, mb2;
    private Texture title_background, title, play_button, instructions_button, about_button, black_bottom;
    private Sprite titleSprite, playButtonSprite, instructionsButtonSprite, aboutButtonSprite, blackBottomSprite;
    private GameButton playBtn, instructionsBtn, aboutBtn;

    private static Music title_music;

    private long timeTouchUp;
    private boolean playUp, instructionsUp, aboutUp;

    private int touchX, touchY;

    private AssetManager assets; //loaded in SplashScreen

    public MenuScreen(Application game, AssetManager assets){
        this.game = game;

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Application.WIDTH, Application.HEIGHT);
        viewport = new FitViewport(Application.WIDTH, Application.HEIGHT, cam);

        this.assets = assets;
        queueAssets();

        title_background = assets.get("menu/title_background.png", Texture.class);
        title = assets.get("menu/title.png", Texture.class);
        play_button = assets.get("menu/play_button.png", Texture.class);
        instructions_button = assets.get("menu/instructions_button.png", Texture.class);
        about_button = assets.get("menu/about_button.png", Texture.class);
        black_bottom = assets.get("menu/black_bottom.png", Texture.class);


        titleSprite = new Sprite(title);
        playButtonSprite = new Sprite(play_button);
        instructionsButtonSprite = new Sprite(instructions_button);
        aboutButtonSprite = new Sprite(about_button);
        blackBottomSprite = new Sprite(black_bottom);

        playBtn = new GameButton();
        instructionsBtn = new GameButton();
        aboutBtn = new GameButton();

        mb = new MenuBackground(1);
        mb2 = new MenuBackground(2);

        title_music = assets.get("music/title_screen.mp3", Music.class);
        title_music.setLooping(true);
        title_music.play();

        gameIcon = new GameIcon(Application.WIDTH/2 - Application.WIDTH/10, Application.HEIGHT/10);

        effect = new ParticleEffect();
        effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("game/particles1.party"), Gdx.files.internal("game"));
        effect.start();

        timeTouchUp = 0;

        //setting things

        mb.getSprite().setX(0);
        mb2.getSprite().setX(0);

        blackBottomSprite.setSize(Application.WIDTH, Application.HEIGHT * 3 / 4);
        blackBottomSprite.setAlpha(1f);

        titleSprite.setSize(Application.WIDTH, Application.WIDTH * 0.5f); //width, height
        titleSprite.setPosition(Application.WIDTH / 2 - titleSprite.getWidth() / 2, Application.HEIGHT / 2 * 1.35f);

        playBtn.setTexture(play_button);
        playBtn.setOrigSize(titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.7f, titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.127f);
        playBtn.setOrigPosition(cam.position.x - playBtn.getWidth() / 2, cam.position.y + 80);

        instructionsBtn.setTexture(instructions_button);
        instructionsBtn.setOrigSize(titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.7f, titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.127f);
        instructionsBtn.setOrigPosition(cam.position.x - instructionsBtn.getWidth() / 2, cam.position.y + 10);

        aboutBtn.setTexture(about_button);
        aboutBtn.setOrigSize(titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.7f, titleSprite.getWidth() * 0.127f);
        aboutBtn.setOrigPosition(cam.position.x - aboutBtn.getWidth() / 2, cam.position.y - 60);

        gameIcon.setSize(50, 50);
        gameIcon.setPosition(Application.WIDTH / 2 - Application.WIDTH / 20, Application.HEIGHT / 10 + 10);
        gameIcon.setvX(0);
        gameIcon.setvY(0);
    }

    public void queueAssets() {
        assets.load("fonts/fixedsys.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
        assets.load("menu/black_bottom.png", Texture.class);
        assets.load("level_select/play_level.png", Texture.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        cam.update();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        game.batch.begin();

        mb.update();
        mb2.update();
        mb.getSprite().setY(mb.getPosition().y);
        mb2.getSprite().setY(mb2.getPosition().y);

        mb.getSprite().draw(game.batch);
        mb2.getSprite().draw(game.batch);

        blackBottomSprite.draw(game.batch);

        titleSprite.draw(game.batch);

        playBtn.update();
        playBtn.draw(game.batch);

        instructionsBtn.update();
        instructionsBtn.draw(game.batch);

        aboutBtn.update();
        aboutBtn.draw(game.batch);

        gameIcon.draw(game.batch);

        effect.getEmitters().first().setPosition(Application.WIDTH / 2 - Application.WIDTH / 20 + gameIcon.getWidth() / 2, Application.HEIGHT / 10 + 10); //doesnt follow gameIcon
        effect.update(delta);
        effect.draw(game.batch);

        game.batch.end();

        gameIcon.update();

        if (TimeUtils.timeSinceMillis(timeTouchUp) > 100 && assets.update()) {
            if (playUp) {
                game.setScreen(new LevelSelectScreen(game, assets, mb.getSprite().getY(), mb2.getSprite().getY(), gameIcon));
                dispose();
            }
            else if(instructionsUp) {

            }
            else if(aboutUp) {

            }
        }

    }

    public static void stopMenuMusic()
    {
        title_music.stop();
        title_music.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        title_background.dispose();
        title.dispose();
        play_button.dispose();
        instructions_button.dispose();
        about_button.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        touchX = GameButton.convertX(screenX);
        touchY = GameButton.convertY(screenY);

        if(playBtn.checkCoords(touchX, touchY))
        {
            playBtn.clickDown();
        }
        else if(instructionsBtn.checkCoords(touchX, touchY))
        {
            instructionsBtn.clickDown();
        }
        else if(aboutBtn.checkCoords(touchX, touchY))
        {
            aboutBtn.clickDown();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        timeTouchUp = TimeUtils.millis();
        if (playBtn.checkCoords(touchX, touchY)) {
            playUp = true;
            playBtn.clickUp();
        }
        else if(instructionsBtn.checkCoords(touchX, touchY))
        {
            instructionsUp = true;
            instructionsBtn.clickUp();
        }
        else if(aboutBtn.checkCoords(touchX, touchY))
        {
            aboutUp = true;
            aboutBtn.clickUp();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isClicked(Sprite sprite, float x, float y)
    {
        if (x >= sprite.getX() && x <= sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth())
        {
            if (y >= sprite.getY() && y <= sprite.getY() + sprite.getHeight())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

After clicking a button on the above screen, it should load this one:

```
public class LevelSelectScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{

    private Application game;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private Viewport viewport;

    private ParticleEffect effect;

    private Texture black_bottom, play_level_button;
    private Sprite blackBottomSprite;

    private String[] levelNames;

    private int maxLevel, level, touchX, touchY;
    private long timeTouchUp;

    private GameButton playLevelBtn;

    private GameIcon gameIcon;

    private MenuBackground mb, mb2;

    private boolean playUp;

    private BitmapFont font;
    public GlyphLayout levelLayout, levelNameLayout;

    private AssetManager assets; //loaded in MenuScreen

    public LevelSelectScreen(Application game, AssetManager assets, float mbY, float mb2Y, GameIcon gameIcon) {
        this.game = game;
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        this.assets = assets;
        queueAssets();

        levelNames = new String[2];
        levelNames[0] = "PLACEHOLDER";
        levelNames[1] = "Taking Off";
        maxLevel = levelNames.length - 1;
        level = 1;

        font = assets.get("fonts/fixedsys.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
        font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        levelLayout = new GlyphLayout(font, "Level " + level);
        levelNameLayout = new GlyphLayout(font, levelNames[0]);

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Application.WIDTH, Application.HEIGHT);
        viewport = new FitViewport(Application.WIDTH, Application.HEIGHT, cam);

        mb = new MenuBackground(mbY, true);
        mb2 = new MenuBackground(mb2Y, true);

        this.gameIcon = new GameIcon(Application.WIDTH / 2 - Application.WIDTH / 20, Application.HEIGHT / 10 + 10);

        black_bottom = assets.get("menu/black_bottom.png", Texture.class);
        play_level_button = assets.get("level_select/play_level.png", Texture.class);

        blackBottomSprite = new Sprite(black_bottom);

        //setting stuff
        mb.getSprite().setX(0);
        mb2.getSprite().setX(0);

        blackBottomSprite.setSize(Application.WIDTH, Application.HEIGHT * 3 / 4);
        blackBottomSprite.setAlpha(1f);

        this.gameIcon.setRotation(gameIcon.getRotation());
        this.gameIcon.setSize(gameIcon.getWidth(), gameIcon.getHeight());
        this.gameIcon.setvX(0);
        this.gameIcon.setvY(0);

        playLevelBtn = new GameButton();
        playLevelBtn.setTexture(play_level_button);
        playLevelBtn.setOrigSize(150, 90);
        playLevelBtn.setOrigPosition(
                Application.WIDTH / 2 - playLevelBtn.getWidth() / 2,
                this.gameIcon.getX() + this.gameIcon.getHeight() + 70);

        effect = new ParticleEffect();
        effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("game/particles1.party"), Gdx.files.internal("game"));
        effect.start();

        playUp = false;

    }

    public void queueAssets() {
        assets.load("game/backgrounds/shadow_mask.png", Texture.class);
        assets.load("game/backgrounds/background_orange.png", Texture.class);
        assets.load("game/border_left.png", Texture.class);
        assets.load("game/border_right.png", Texture.class);
        assets.load("game/backgrounds/white_only.png", Texture.class);
        assets.load("game/backgrounds/circles_pattern.png", Texture.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        cam.update();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        game.batch.begin();

        mb.update();
        mb2.update();
        mb.getSprite().setY(mb.getPosition().y);
        mb2.getSprite().setY(mb2.getPosition().y);

        mb.getSprite().draw(game.batch);
        mb2.getSprite().draw(game.batch);
        blackBottomSprite.draw(game.batch);

        gameIcon.update();
        gameIcon.draw(game.batch);

        levelLayout.setText(font, "Level " + level);
        levelNameLayout.setText(font, levelNames[level]);
        font.draw(
                game.batch,
                "Level " + level,
                Application.WIDTH / 2 - levelLayout.width / 2,
                Application.HEIGHT / 2 + levelLayout.height / 2
        );

        effect.getEmitters().first().setPosition(Application.WIDTH / 2 - Application.WIDTH / 20 + gameIcon.getWidth() / 2, Application.HEIGHT / 10 + 10); //doesnt follow gameIcon
        effect.update(delta);
        effect.draw(game.batch);

        playLevelBtn.update();
        playLevelBtn.draw(game.batch);

        game.batch.end();

        if (TimeUtils.timeSinceMillis(timeTouchUp) > 100 && assets.update()) {
            if (playUp) {                game.setScreen(new com.xx4everPixelatedxx.gaterunner.screens.Levels.Level1Screen(game, assets));

                MenuScreen.stopMenuMusic();
                dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        touchX = GameButton.convertX(screenX);
        touchY = GameButton.convertY(screenY);

        if(playLevelBtn.checkCoords(touchX, touchY))
        {
            playLevelBtn.clickDown();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        timeTouchUp = TimeUtils.millis();
        if (playLevelBtn.checkCoords(touchX, touchY)) {
            playUp = true;
            playLevelBtn.clickUp();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you have not guessed it by now, my question is this: How can I make the screen to screen transition on my Android device take less time?

Comment: This is a lot of code. Please edit your question to only include the relevant parts of code.

Comment: I'm afraid that if I remove any code, I might be removed the code where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

I am more than sure that your problem is in the loading resources. Please notice that although you are loading assets for **LevelSelectScreen** in **MenuScreen** you are still calling **queueAssets();** in LevelSelect constructor.

Make a little test - remove all assets and ui elements using them and then check loading time.

**First of all** reduce count of loaded textures by packing them into [TextureAtlas](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#textureatlas) using [TexturePacker](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer). I/O operations are really expensive.

Secondly you can make the ResourcesManager (for example implementing [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) and keeping its static instance, loading all resources at the beggining of the application.

Comment: I made my AssetManager static in my Application class and loaded all the resources first, and now I think it is a bit faster (or maybe its the placebo effect). Later, I will try to figure out how to use TextureAtlas and TexturePacker.

Comment: first of all try to do a test I told you - remove (comment :) ) all  assets usage to check if it is the problem - then you can create some improvements.
Unfortunately making AssetManager static cannot help - it's placebo. You should make AssetManager static and **out of Screen classes** keeping all assets being loaded at the app launching. Of course it is not that simple and generally it is wide topic to do it right - but it can be the first approach